# Viewing Image Inside Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I would like to know if there's a way - *without* installing a third party program - to view a graphical item, such as a photo, inside terminal.

I'm running **Ubuntu 17.04**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without 3rd party applications, `terminal` cannot display graphics. It's only resolution is the text block.

Answer (score 0):

you can not view image inside the normal terminal.You can do that with some advance terminals.But I am going to tell you the another way for gnome terminal and other basic terminals in which you need to call the images with some other application.

suppose if you want to view xyz.png then type

`xviewer xyz.png` or

`gwenview xyz.png` or

`gpicview xyz.png`

depending upon your desktop environment.

**Note:** you can install xviewer by command

`sudo apt install xviewer`

and gpicview by

`sudo apt install gpicview`

and gwenview by

`sudo apt install gwenview`